# How to get element presence in Boolean type in Selenium 3 (instead of isElementPresent)

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, selenium2library, selenium3

I am trying to learn automation testing with WebDriverJS-Mocha in NodeJS via guidance of page at below, which the scenario was being coded compatible with Selenium 2(not compatible with Selenium 3):
https://watirmelon.blog/2015/10/28/getting-started-with-webdriverjs-mocha/

And, I just want to know how to get element presence in Boolean type in Selenium 3 *as it is 'isElementPresent' in Selenium 2*

I am using two npm packages:

```
npm install selenium-webdriver@3.4.0
npm install -g mocha
```

I am running my js file as below:

```
mocha spec.js
```

I tried to code it as below:

```
driver.findElements(By.id('sampleID')).then(found => true, function(present) {
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('sampleID')), 3000);
        assert.equal(present, true, "Quote container not displayed");
    });
```

Comment: can you try this...., var answer = driver.findElements(By.id(""));  now Boolean(answer) will return true if the element exist. This is just a thought and i am a java programmer.

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work. I found some assertions like "element.size > 0". I will try to find, but there should be a method instead of 'isElementPresent()'.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with below method...

```
public boolean checkForPresenceOfElementByXpath(String xpath){
    try{
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should wrap your `findElements` INSIDE the wait, and not wrap the wait inside the findElements. You first wait until the first element is found and then you find all the elements.

However I also think you can accomplish this with `elementLocated` by itself.

Instead of:

```
driver.findElements(By.id('sampleID')).then(function(present) {
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('sampleID')), 3000);
    assert.equal(present, true, "Quote container not displayed");
});
```

Just do

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#sampleID')), 3000).then(function(present){
    assert.equal(present, true, "Quote container not displayed");
});
```

If that doesn't do what you want and you need findELements, do the wait first then do whatever you want with findElements.

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#sampleID')), 3000);
driver.findElements(By.css('#sampleID')).then(function(els){
    assert.equal(present, true, "Quote container not displayed");
});
```